# how to query the number of entries in Room

Tags: android-room

What is equivalent to DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries for SQLite library in Room?

Do we need to write the count query as below? Any annotation?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM tableName")
LiveData<Integer> getRowCount();
```

Comment: Thank you, joao! Actually, I'm wondering if there's any other way than @Query.

Comment: I don't think there is, simply based on the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary#annotations